# Presenting UIImagePickerController from modal ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

Have such part of my storyboard:

[image]

So I want present from UserProfileController: UIViewController "Мой профиль", which is modal, (on the top on image) UIImageViewController.

My code:

```
extension UserProfileController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBAction func imagePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        userProfileImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Well, imagePickerController presented, but after I choose image I have dismissed both controllers (imagePickerController and parent - UserProfileControler).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

P.S. May be problem is I'm showing "SideMenuNavigationController" as modal? (so advised in SideMenu framework documentation)

Comment: Could try to put the @IBAction outside the extension?

Comment: Already did it, IBAction same as imagePicker: didFinish method in declaration class body

Answer (score 0):

Try to create you UIImagePickerController reference in your class (as a variable)

```
// to choose an image from the Camera Roll
    fileprivate lazy var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = {
        let picker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        picker.delegate = self

        return picker
    }()
```